# Browserify API alternative to --ingore-missing?

Tags: browserify

When using the Browserify CLI to bundle files, you can use the `--ignore-missing` flag to ignore all missing dependencies in the file.

What is the programmable API alternative to that? The `opts` object doesn't seem to have an alternative either, and I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `.exclude()` method on a browserify instance.